# Nodejs + redis + displaying results on the browser

Tags: node.js, redis

I am having trouble displaying the results that I retrieve from redis with the redis driver in nodejs.

I display an array that initially was a JSON, but it displays lots of "/n" between the elements and properties and I have spent hours trying to fix it but I did not succeed.

Any hint about how can I present the information in the browser without the "/n" characters?

`JSON.stringify`? I have try it and no way. `util.inspect`... I have try it. I know I am doing something wrong but I cannot find what.

My code goes like this:

```
app.get('/retrieve_from_redis_promise', function(req, res) {

  client.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('Connected to Redis succesfully');
  });

  var p = new Promise(function(res, reject) {

    if (true) {
      client.hgetall("redis_db_name", function(err, replies) {
        res(replies)
        // Object.keys(replies).forEach(key => {});
      });
    } else {
      reject(Error("It broke"));
    }

  });

  p.then(function(result) {
    res.send(result); // "Stuff worked!"
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err); // Error: "It broke"
  });

});
```

Comment: Now I can see that displaying just one element the "/n" characters do not appear beetween the properties. But I am trying to retrieve all of them.

Comment: Did you try to use replace to ged rid of all /n like so.. EachElement.replace(/\n/g, "")?

Comment: I try replace already, but I am going to try again right now. thnks

Comment: I have a question: whats the type of replies in my code....I mean: it is not a string already. It is a promise in this moment?

Comment: replace cannot be applied there I think, because it gives an error

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
client.hgetall("redis_db_name", function(err, replies) {
    Object.keys(replies).forEach(key => {
        replies[key] = JSON.parese(replies[key]);
    });
    res(replies)
});
```

Comment: I just try it and unexpected token at first position...I am going to study with more detail the required steps. Thanks a lot.